# CakePHP 1.3: Video Plugin

Tags: facebook, api, cakephp, video, youtube

I am trying to develop a small section in my site, where I can post videos to the site. At this point instead of worrying about uploads and processing every video that I upload, I wanted to opt for Youtube or Facebook integration.

The idea is to upload videos to youtube or facebook, thru the admin section of my site, and have it automatically show up in my list of videos on the site, which will force me to deal with their APIs.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can accomplish this or if there is any CakePHP plugins that can accomplish this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some information on how you could start.

1. [Download](http://framework.zend.com/releases/ZendGdata-1.11.10/ZendGdata-1.11.10.tar.gz) the Zend Google Data (GData) API.
2. There is a very [simple guide](http://www.alexmbarton.com/code/using-gdata-and-cakephp) that explains how to integrate GData with Cakephp.

The Zend GData API lets you interact with Google's web applications such as Youtube.

The Zend framework (framework.zend.com) has an extended documentation on how to use the GData API.

Hope this helps